# ng-repeat is not working inside the table row

Tags: angularjs

I want to fetch the data inside table but not getting any data.
Code is here--

```
 <div ng-controller="tenders"> 
                <table ng-init="getViewProjectDetail('<?php echo $project_id ; ?>')">
                  <thead> 
                        <tr class="active">
                            <th colspan="4">
                                Project Detail:
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th><b>Project Name :</b></th>
                            <td ng-repeat="a in viewProjects">
                                {{a.id}}
                            </td>
                         {{viewProjects | json}}
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

getting all data in viewProjects through json but unable to print it inside table row n each function of controller services and models working perfactly except this.

Please help me to get this issue.

Comment: post the `viewProjects` array

Comment: Add ng-repeat to tr.and just print <td>{{a.id}} </td>.it may helps.

Comment: In your`thead` you have one `th`while in your `tbody`you have one `th` and n `td`. Conceptually it's wrong,  I suggest that you add the `ng-repeat` on a `tr` and inside it you add `<td>{{a.id}} </td>`

Comment: "<pre>Array\n(\n [0] => stdClass Object\n (\n [id] => 1\n [project_title] => Integrated Water And Waste Water Management Smart Metering\n [project_desc] => Integrated Water And Waste Water Management Smart Metering\n [state_id] => 1\n [cost] => 25000\n [updated_on] => 2017-03-17 12:03:00\n [create_date] => 2017-03-17 05:15:29\n [modify_date] => 2017-03-25 15:28:37\n [status] => Active\n [userby] => 1\n )\n\n)\n</pre>";

This is the viewProject array @sachila ranawaka

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<ng-container ng-repeat=""></ng-container>` for any angularJS condition without use any html element as below :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>xyz</td>
    <ng-container ng-repeat="a in myArray">
      <td>{{a.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should loop over tr instead of td in this case

```
<div ng-controller="tenders"> 
    <table ng-init="getViewProjectDetail('<?php echo $project_id ; ?>')">
      <thead> 
            <tr class="active">
                <th colspan="4">
                    Project Detail:
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="a in viewProjects">
                <td><b>Project Name :</b></td>
                <td >
                    {{a.id}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried this but unable to fetch data in table row

Comment: @user6891871 then the question is what does viewProjects holds? could you share the array details?

Comment: i have shared it at the top.. Please check it

Comment: @user6891871 That is not a valid array. First of, its a string. Secondly, it contains <pre> tabs and lot of different crazy stuff.